# hitTest(_:options:) for SCNNodes without physicsBody swift

Tags: ios, swift, collision-detection, scenekit, hittest

I'm trying to determine how to do a 'hitTest' without actually creating a physicsBody for my SCNNode.

What alternative can I use for a hit test method? (that includes nodes without a physics body). I'm trying to select the first node that the screen touch is on

**Problem**, the 'hit test' requires that the node have a physicsBody
This would work if I had a physicsBody, but I need to do stuff with my SCNNode before I add the physicsBody.

My 'environmentContainer' DOES have the first SCNNode in it; however, the 'results.first' returned the first node with a physicsBody, I need the first node (regardless if it has a physicsBody or not)

```
case .began:
    let results = sceneView.hitTest(firstTouch!, options: [SCNHitTestOption.firstFoundOnly: true])
    if results.first != nil {
        if environmentContainer.childNodes.contains((results.first?.node)!)
        {
            firstDragTapOnSelectedNode = true
            print("firstDragTapOnSelectedNode = true")
        }
        else {
            // always returns false because 'results.first' is picking up the wrong node which is in a different SCNNode container
            print("firstDragTapOnSelectedNode = false")
        }
    }
case .ended:
    firstDragTapOnSelectedNode = false
default: break
}
```

Note: firstDragTapOnSelectedNode is initialized to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SceneKit hit test is testing against geometries by default. You can set `SCNHitTestOption.boundingBoxOnly` to true to check against the bounding box of the node instead. 
Hit testing should have nothing to do with the `physicsBody` just with geometries and bounding boxes.

Comment: I checked the documentation for hitTest after I read your post (then was in no wifi zone the rest of the week), and confirmed that it didn't say anything about requiring a physicsBody (must have gotten it mixed up with rayTestWithSegment and convexSweepTest I was experimenting with at the same time), then why would my code not work? I think the 'boundingBoxOnly' was a good suggestion, but that didn't seem to help either ... the only thing that I've been able to get work is to (oddly) get rid if the 'SCNHitTestOption.firstFoundOnly', but leave everything else the same.

Comment: Shouldn't the 'results.first != nil' have been the same before AND after I added the 'SCNHitOption.firstFoundOnly' option? (note the node being tapped is in the foreground of the screen)

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't get the hit test to work without a geometry at all, after setting the geometry the `boundingBoxOnly` key works as expected. Does your node has a geometry attached?

Comment: It sure does have a geometry (SCNBox so boundingBoxOnly shouldn't make a difference), and as you said, it doesn't require a physics body, but I can only get the hitTest to work when it does not have the 'SCNHitTestOption.firstFoundOnly' option ... my only other idea on this is that the implementation of the hitTest does not go in order from closest to furthest for all geometry nodes. It's not a huge problem, as I'm only performing the hitTest on a user interaction trigger, so it won't happen consistently, but still odd.

Comment: ... Note, when I have my node floating in the air (without a physicsbody) with no other nodes in front of or behind it, it doesn't pick up the node when it has the 'SCNHitTestOption.firstFoundOnly' option also, so it makes me think that this particular option is meant for collision purposes. Only when I don't include that option, then the node I'm trying to select is 'results.first.node' as expected